# If I have no ties to my home country, can I get a tourst visa by being in a good financial position?

Tags: usa, uk, schengen, tourist-visas

No house, car, loan, marriage, job. Only significant ties to my home country are my investment lands (just sitting there for appreciation), my parents and my emotions.

- If you ask me, lands aren't really ties because I can sell them remotely using a power of attorney.
- Idk how I'm supposed to prove my ties to my parents well enough to convince visa dudes that I'm coming back. Everyone have parents. I actually asked an embassy and they told me they have no suggestions about any specific documents I can provide.
- Well I don't think I can document my emotions but I tried living in multiple countries to see if I want to move to one of them but I found that I like living in my home country. So its the best country for me for long term living. So far at least.

The banks I actively use and +99% of my liquid NW are located outside of my home country.

I'd just apply without asking here but once you get rejected for a visa, that stays on record for life and creates **issues** if you want to buy a passport or apply to visas. From what I can tell visa dudes don't really ask questions or request documents. They just hit the red button.

Comment: Nobody knows. Give it a shot

Comment: Can you show that you need to return to your home country to manage your land, or its rental, with bank statements showing relevant income from it? You can show family ties, too, they are in your home country, and no, not everyone has parents.

Comment: @WeatherVane Lands aren't suitable for renting or managing. They're solely for appreciation. How can I show family ties? I researched about this but there's no concrete ideas about what documents to provide

Comment: @AugustineofHippo Like I said I'd give it a shot but I think not giving a shot to make sure I don't get rejected for a visa might be a better idea

Comment: There’s nothing unique about your situation. I also visited the USA the first time as a senior in university. I had NOTHING except my parents and incomplete degree to tie me to my home country. Your chances are very slim, no question however not impossible. Of course you can postpone applying until your profile is more favorable, a rejection doesn’t help for future travel.

Comment: @AugustineofHippo You had a motivation to come back to finish your degree. How did you document your ties to your parents?

Comment: You've tagged this question as 3 different localities, but you indicate in which direction you want to travel, or what your nationality and/or residency is.  That sort of information will help drive an answer.

Comment: @PeterM I'm interested in all 3 of them. Do you suggest me to post the same thing and tag a different country for each one? --- How could my nationality/residency help? Its clearly not a great one since I am here

Comment: For starters different localities will impose their own requirements for what is reasonable or not to issue a visa.  So the more specific the question, the more specific the answer will be.  This site prefers specific, answerable questions over general and vague questions.   Your nationality and residency will help to identify possible roadblocks and/or corner cases to specific localities that you may not have considered. EG establishing a solid travel record to some 4th, 5th or 6th locations before applying to the areas you have listed in your question.

Comment: You mention you have traveled to other countries, it may help if you mention your home country and those you have traveled to, as we can then assess whether they are helpful in your case or not much.

Comment: Are you still a citizen of your home country? If so, you should be able to enter freely without a visa. If not, the "visa dudes" in the home country won't be interested in your home country ties, but instead your ties to wherever you live now. They'll want to be convinced that, after the term of your visa, the strong ties to where you live now will compel you to leave the home country and return to where you live now, instead of staying in the home country.

Comment: You need to apply with a positive attitude, and not provide defeatist arguments for refusal. That's the job of the visa officer; yours is to present a good case. If you own land in your country - tell them , and show it. If you have family in your country - tell them, and prove it. Etc.

Comment: If you are not wealthy or famous, forget it. Your chances are slim and none and slim is out of town. I would say forget it because you seem like the average Joe and without those ties which even the average Joe has binding them to their home country.

Answer (score 2):

If you feel that you have to prove your ties to your home country, then how about the visa "dudes"? if you aren't sure, for sure they won't be as well.

Recently and due to the many wars around the world, the financial position itself does not seem enough to prove ties. Many rich people, for example from Syria, applies for tourist visas then never leave. I am sure if a simple person like me noticed this, the visa "dudes" for sure have noticed it.

If you are from a stable country, you have a better chance of getting the visa based on your financial status. However, if you are from an untestable country, then things might be different. You most likely will need to have a job certificate at minimum to prove some sort of ties.

Finally, you are overthinking it, if you have travelled as much as you claim, then mention that in the "countries visited in the past X years" field, this field is there for some reasons, proving ties is one of them.

Comment: I’m pretty sure that past a certain net worth the “visa dudes” in many countries don’t care a bit about your ties to your country. If you are rich enough to spend lots of money in the country and not be a burden, you are usually most welcome. The trouble is of course determining how much is that “certain net worth”.

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to advise without more specifics. A Japanese citizen with funds but no job would be treated differently from a Syrian citizen in the same economic situation.

- **Right now** tourist travel is severely restricted because of the pandemic.  It will matter how prevalent various COVID strains are in your country of residence. By the time that is over, both the rules and your situation might have changed enough to make the current answer irrelevant.
- They want to **predict overstay risks** on that tourist visa. Ties to the home country are one way. If you would qualify for an investor visa e.g. in Malta any time you decide to spend the money, that would also make you a lower risk on a tourist visa.
  You wrote "buy a passport" in your post, so presumably you have considered doing that yourself.
- When it comes to funds, read up on the concept of funds parking. The visa officials will want to be sure that the money is really yours and not borrowed for this purposes.
- Visa officials **prefer normal cases**. Having to explain why your case is special is a bad thing.

Comment: See also: [Funds Parking: What Is the Purpose of Bank Statements?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/66105/95267)